Dataweave: How to filter elements on the array from a different attribute in the same array of objects?
Could you please help me with Mulesoft dataweave script for below transformation.
Input Json:
[
  {
    "schoolName": "ABC",
    "SchoolId": "3444444",
    "AreaId": "2334555",
    "Number": "100"
  },
  {
    "schoolName": "ABC",
    "SchoolId": "77655444",
    "AreaId": "3444444",
    "Number": "100"
  },
  {
    "schoolName": "ABC",
    "SchoolId": "456666",
    "AreaId": "77655444",
    "Number": "100"
  },
  {
    "schoolName": "ABC",
    "SchoolId": "2334555",
    "AreaId": "555555",
    "Number": "100"
  }
]

Output Json: where AreaId not match with SchoolId in all JSON objects in array.
[
  {
    "schoolName": "ABC",
    "SchoolId": "23445",
    "AreaId": "555555",
    "Number": "100"
  }    
]


The title doesn't reflect de question. Please edit it.

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for elements in the payload whose AreaId does not match any other element's SchoolId.
If that's correct, you could filter elements in your payload like this:
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var allSchoolIds = payload.SchoolId
---
payload filter (not (allSchoolIds contains $.AreaId))

and using the input your question, your output will look like:
[
  {
    "schoolName": "ABC",
    "SchoolId": "2334555",
    "AreaId": "555555",
    "Number": "100"
  }
]


HI blurfus, Thanks for the reply. this is what I was looking for. Appriciate the quick responce.

glad I could be of help :)

Very fine solution @rohitbit00 -- I also prefer to isolate logic into variables rather than cram everything inline with the filter() lambda. Nice work

Thanks... I also find it easier to read and maintain later on :)
